# Google Pay using Sripe : Getting an unexpected developer error in Android

Tags: android, stripe-payments, google-pay

I have Implemented google pay using stripe payment processor and it is in test Environment. When I used to test google pay with real card payment it shows a dialog box that

> "Request Failed"
>
> UnExpected developer error, Please try again later.

I am unclear why this error is showing. How to resolve these issue. Can Anyone help me out?

> Manifest file

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="myproject"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
            android:value="true" />
</application>
```

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions declared in your manifest?  They're in the Stripe Google Pay for Android docs.  Often times it's caused by people embedding the permissions in the wrong spot.

Comment: yes, I have added  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
    android:value="true" />

Comment: I have added my manifest file .can u check it. If anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

More detailed information is shared in the logs. Make sure to remove any process/application specific filtering, since these logs emanate away from your application. If you filter using a keyword such as "wallet", you should be able to see more specific hints into your problem.

Let me know whether that helps.